# parseInt doesn't work well in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
arr = ["1","2"];

$.each(arr,function(i,obj){
                sum += parseInt(obj);
});
console.log(sum);
```

I expect the sum would be 3 but the result is 12? I thought parseInt already did the job? What's wrong here?

Comment: Its is concatinating 1 and 2

Comment: Your code works as expected, https://jsbin.com/qedofehebo/edit?html,js,console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198131/parseint-inside-for-in-loop/62198672#62198672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in behavior is on how you are initializing sum

```
if var sum = 0; -> result will be as expected i.e. 3

if var sum = ""; -> result will be 12 as coming because sum is string
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here the working code

```
 var arr = ["1","2"];
    var sum=0;
    $.each(arr,function(i,obj){
                    sum += parseInt(obj);
    });
    alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alice Xu your code is not incorrect actually. This is the problem as somewhere before this in your code sum variable is getting treated as empty string so here while addition

```
sum += parseInt(obj);
```

object is converting to the Int but then again to the string as sum is of string type. So what we are getting is concatenation of 1 and 2 which is "12" as you pointed out so It would be just fine if you initialize sum to zero.

I have ran your code and got NaN as output because I did not initialize sum at all. It seems that you are initializing it to "" as you got "12" as output.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
function sumArray(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
var sum = sumArray(['1', '2', 3]);
```

Using JavaScript [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```
var array = ['1', '2', 3];
var sum = array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + parseInt(b); }, 0);
```