# ParseInt inside for in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

Is there a simple way to remove the `key = parseInt( key );` and get the key direct as integer from the for?

```
for( var key in object.items )
{
    key = parseInt( key );
}
```

**Edit for better understanding**

object.items is a object with ids as keys. **But not a array**.

```
object.items = {
    "123": "somthing",
    "745": "somthing",
    "975": "somthing"
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to add some more context to that code snippet. What is `object` in this context? what is `object.items`?

Comment: Also, if `object.items` is an array, do _not_ use for...in, either use a normal for loop, or use `.forEach()`, but in this case I'm 99.9% sure you want `.map()` instead, to generate a new array with all values converted to integers.

Comment: `parseInt(...)` is *mostly* for when you're getting $(somelement).val(), which will be a text-type.  Also, I recommend `parseInt(..., 10)`.

Comment: Maybe You need something like that: `["1","2","3","4"].map(x => parseInt(x))`

Comment: @ Olian04 @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: Why do you need to parse the keys as numbers?

Comment: @VLAZ I need the ids to see if they are in an other array. Where only the ids are stored.

Comment: Just fyi, you will need to use Object.keys(object.items) to extract the keys from the object. Using parseInt() within the loop should work fine, but you could use map as @ŁukaszOlszewski suggests to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will extract the keys for you:

```
Object.keys(object.items);
```

Now if we want all of them as integer.

```
Object.keys(object.items).map(Number);
```